# Text on page has no size and just colapses into itself

Tags: css, grid

I have no idea what might be causing it. Of note is that I'm using normalize and this is how my base css file looks like:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
    font-size: 6.25%; // 1rem = 1px
}

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lctq.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aXOG.png)

Comment: Hi, please include relevant HTML and CSS, thanks

Comment: this looks like your line-height is broken, but cant really tell without "working" code

Comment: thank you Dirk it was the line-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use property `line-height`